# The type 'Page' does not support direct content - VS for Mac

Tags: uno-platform

```xml
<Page
  [...]>
  <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RowDetailsTemplate">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock [...]" />
        <Grid [...]>
```

The XAML code is underlined (The type 'Page' does not support direct content) and it doesn't build.

I've read the uno platform docs and other questions here, but my problem is on Visual Studio for Mac. There is no option to change the project on the top left corner to the UWP project.

Answer (score 1):

The project should still compile.

It's a known problem and usually related to the designer.  [More details here](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/2859).